# How to write the connection string of OLE DB in Excel 2007?

Tags: excel, ms-access, oledb, oledbconnection

I need this method of creating a connection because my access file is password protected.

Using Excel 2016, you just have to write down a connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\Users\Asus\Google Drive\Test\System Improvement\Test.mdb";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="test";
```

And the SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM JO
```

Then just follow the wizard to make a successful connection of my Access file to my Excel file. However, when using Excel 2007, the string's format that I entered in Excel 2016 changes quite a bit and i'm not familiar with them:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=JO (AR Sales);Extended Properties=""
```

Then the SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM [JO (AR Sales)]
```

Comment: This might help https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: Thank you i think it will help